# three.js won't render sphere

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am a THREE.js noob. I copied some code but for some reason my sphere in the middle won't render. Does anyone have ideas? Here's my code:

```html
<canvas id='canvas' width='960' height='720'></canvas>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/threejs/r69/three.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  var T = THREE;
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var WIDTH = 960, HEIGHT = 720;
  var VIEW_ANGLE = 45, ASPECT = WIDTH / HEIGHT, NEAR = 0.1, FAR = 10000;
  var renderer = new T.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
  var camera = new T.PerspectiveCamera(VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR);
  var scene = new T.Scene();
  scene.add(camera);
  camera.position.z = 300;
  renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

  var sphMat = new T.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x778B71});
  var sph = new T.Mesh(new T.SphereGeometry(5, 20, 20), sphMat);
  sph.position.x = 0;
  sph.position.y = 0;
  sph.position.z = 0;
  scene.add(sph);

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  canvas.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please specify what means won't render?
I can't fig. a light source in your code, THREE.MeshLambert mat needs a light.

For testing use MeshBasicMaterial:

http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/MeshBasicMaterial or put a light in to scene:
http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Lights/AmbientLight